# Video recorded via intent seems to be corrupt

Tags: android, android-intent, video

I have to share a video, in my app (that is a chat). So I have done a intent to record it, and then send it.

When I launch the option of share video, the intent opens the camera, I record some seconds of video, and then I shared. It works "fine", until I realized that video can't be reproduced.

When I go to the file browser, I see that the video has the correct name, type, and size, but is can be played.
When I saw this, I thought it was a problem of the phone. So I did a video with the camera app  and it's ok.

Here is a image to show what I mean:

(Te first video is the "corrupted" taken from the (my) chat app)

[image]

And here is the code I'm using to call the intent.

I did something wrong? Or I forget some special parameter?

***Method to call intent:***

```
void startVideoTaker() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        File video = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "cs_"
                + new Date().getTime() + ".mp4");

        mLastVideo = Uri.fromFile(video);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mLastVideo);

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

    }
```

***Piece of code where is received the intent***

```
Uri fileUri = null;
                if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE) {
                    fileUri = mLastVideo;
                } else {
                    fileUri = mLastPhoto;
                }

                File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(fileUri));

                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("FILESENDING", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
                prefsEditor.putString("path", getRealPathFromURI(fileUri));
                prefsEditor.putBoolean("file", true);
                prefsEditor.commit();

                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, final Uri uri) {

                                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE) {
                                            handleSendDelete(mLastVideo, true, false);
                                        } else {
                                            handleSendDelete(mLastPhoto, true, true);
                                        }

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
```